# Swapping two children of parent.parent in jquery not working

Tags: jquery

What am I doing wrong here ?

So i basically want to go back 2 parents from the swap button, which is the main div which contains two specific divs with certain classes "imagentextimage" and "imagentexttext" which I want to swap.

also, is there a better way to just say "swap" instead of having to check wheter an element is before or after another and then swap according to that ? Because i only want to swap then back and forth.

my html is this

```
<div class="smallbox-wrapper imagentextboxicon" id="row1">
<div class="widewrapper">
    <input type="button" class="swapbutton" value="⇔">
    <input type="button" class="deletebutton " value="X" onclick="delete_row('row2')">
</div>

<div class="smallbox imagentextimage">
    <div class="smallbox twoxboximage" contenteditable="true" placeholder="image.."></div>
</div>

<div class="smallbox imagentexttext">
    <div class="smallbox twoxboximage" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Optional Image.."></div>
    <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboxheader" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Optional Header.."></div>
    <div class="smallbox twoxboxtext" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Text.."></div>
</div>

<div class="up"></div>
<div class="down"></div>
</div>
```

And I have this Js which fires if i click the swap button

```
//Swap button (for image & text)
$(document).on('click', ".swapbutton", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent(".imagentexttext").before($(this).parent().parent(".imagentextimage"));
});
```

the button does work with alert(); but here I don't get any errors and don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

Can someone explain to me why this isn't working please.

Much appreciated.
Love
Gram

Comment: I can't see any ancestor with `imagentexttext` class, also, why not just use `closest` if you know the class of the ancestor you want

Comment: Why are you doing that with reference of parents, if there is only one whole structure of such HTML then just target those divs with their classes. Simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find image and text inside parent of parent of button using `closest` and then check index of image and text to decide if image to be added before or after text.

see below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.swapbutton').click(function(){
    var $parent = $(this).closest('div.smallbox-wrapper');
    var $text = $parent.find('.imagentexttext');
    var textIndex = $text.index();
    var $img = $parent.find('.imagentextimage');
    var imgIndex = $img.index();
    if(textIndex > imgIndex) {
        $img.before($text);
    } else {
      $img.after($text);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smallbox-wrapper imagentextboxicon" id="row1">
<div class="widewrapper">
    <input type="button" class="swapbutton" value="⇔">
    <input type="button" class="deletebutton " value="X" onclick="delete_row('row2')">
</div>

<div class="smallbox imagentextimage">
    <div class="smallbox twoxboximage" contenteditable="true" placeholder="image..">img</div>
</div>

<div class="smallbox imagentexttext">
    <div class="smallbox twoxboximage" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Optional Image..">Text</div>
    <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboxheader" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Optional Header..">test</div>
    <div class="smallbox twoxboxtext" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Text..">text</div>
</div>

<div class="up"></div>
<div class="down"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot ! IT#s working but I just have to use 

$(document).on('click', ".swapbutton", function()

because this isnt working:

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.swapbutton').click(function()

Why is that ?

Comment: you must be adding buttons dynamically? that is the reason click event handler not work with simple class selector because by the time script execute button is not available in DOM but you need to use `document` object to attach the event. See more on https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks yeah that's it !!

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var flag_on = 1;
    $(document).on('click', ".swapbutton", function() {
        if(flag_on == 1){
            $(".imagentexttext").hide();
            $(".imagentextimage").show();
        }else{
            $(".imagentextimage").hide();
            $(".imagentexttext").show();
        }

    });
});
```